# Why does using tabular inside of chemfig's chemname alter the vertical position of the text?

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemfig

`chemfig` offers the `\chemname`  command that allows us to add an annotation (name, number,...) to a chemical compound. To save space and avoid repetition when dealing with similar compounds, "R"  is often used instead of a more specific substituent. "R" is usually defined below the compound. For this, I tried to use the `\chemname{<compound>}{>name>}` command, but with a  `tabular` in the `<name>` part of the command.

While the horizontal alignment looks as expected, the vertical alignment is off, if compared to compounds that are named without using a tabular. (See image below, left: with tabular, middle and right: without tabular). An alternative, that does not alter the vertical position of the text would be using a `\parbox`, but this approach requires determining the width of the text in order to get it centered below the molecule and it does not allow for the same column-like alignment of substituents and numbers, that a `tabular` does.

[image]

What causes this additional white space above text inside of a `tabular` and is there a better way to achieve the desired output?

Here is the code used to create the screenshot shown above.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-OH}}
             {{\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\;}l}
               R = \textit{n}-Bu: & 1a\\
               R = Et: & 1b\\
             \end{tabular}}}
    \chemname{\chemfig{Me-OH}}
             {2}  
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-OH}}
             {\parbox{2.25cm}{R = \textit{n}-Bu:  1a\\ R = Et:  1b\\}}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605961/134144

Comment: Maybe it is due to the strut. What about `{\def\arraystretch{0}\begin{tabular}...\\[5pt]...\end{tabular}}`?

Answer (score 5):

How about this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\chemfig{R-OH}
&
\chemfig{Me-OH}
&
\chemfig{R-OH}
\\
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\;}l}
 R = \textit{n}-Bu: & 1a\\
 R = Et: & 1b
\end{tabular}
&
2
&
\parbox[t]{2.25cm}{
 R = \textit{n}-Bu: 1a\\
 R = Et: 1b
}
\end{tabular}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. While it does work in this particular simplified example, as far as I can tell, it will however lead to inconsistent (horizontal) spacing if used inside of a actual reaction scheme which also includes `\+` and `\arrow`. Especially, if there are other "traditional" schemes using `\chemname` for the naming/numbering part in the same document.

Comment: @leandriis, you are welcome. My impression is that  alignment behavior of chemical reactions involving `\chemname` is somewhat inconsistent and unstable in the current version of `\chemfig`. If you need perfect control of everything in the picture, then you might want to avoid it.